# Jquery add click to slide up panel?

Tags: jquery, animation, panel, toggle, slide

I have the following slide panel, i've cobbled together using tutorials etc...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideDown(150);
});

$(".dropdown dd #panel a").click(function() {

    $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideUp(150);

});

var myTimeout = null; 
$(".dropdown").bind("mouseleave", function() { 
    myTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() { 
         $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideUp(150); // <-- 1000ms  
    }, 1000);$('.dropdown dt a').removeClass('active'); 
}); 

$(".dropdown dd #panel").bind("mouseenter",function() { 
    window.clearTimeout(myTimeout); 
});
```

});

However i cannot figure out how to click to bring up the panel.

Currently you click and the panel slides down, you go into the panel and out and it slides back up.

I want to add that once you've clicked to show panel, you can click to close it too?

So you have two ways of closing it, moving the mouse away,or clicking the button again. Perhaps adding a active class to so i could have an arrow or something changing to open then close?

Anyone help my out adding a click to slide back up function?

Many thanks if you can :)

```
Thanks guys.
```

Tried adding your code Brian but managed to break it altogether, i obviously haven't put it in the right place :(

**edit**

Adding Brians advice...

```
$(document).ready(function() {



$(".dropdown dt a").click(function(){
    if($(".dropdown dd #panel").hasclass('open'){
        $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideDown(150).addClass('open');
    } else {
       $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideUp(150).removeClass('open');
    }
});         


$(".dropdown dd #panel a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideUp(150).removeClass('open');;
});

var myTimeout = null; 
$(".dropdown").bind("mouseleave", function() { 
    myTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() { 
         $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideUp(150); // <-- 1000ms  
    }, 1000);$('.dropdown dt a').removeClass('active'); 
}); 

$(".dropdown dd #panel").bind("mouseenter",function() { 
    window.clearTimeout(myTimeout); 
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to track the state of the panel because you have two close triggers (therefore a simple toggle listener won't suffice). You can add a js variable (ok, but not great) or use a class (better) to track it.  Then conditionally test on you're click listeners to determine what to do:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function(){
    if($(".dropdown dd #panel").hasClass('open'){
        $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideDown(150).addClass('open');
    } else {
       $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideUp(150).removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Just make sure you add the removeClass method to the close listener you have on the interior anchor tag as well:

```
$(".dropdown dd #panel a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd #panel").slideUp(150).removeClass('open');;
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i've added your suggestion above Brian, but i've managed to break it altogether, i assume i put it in the wrong place :(

Comment: You probably need to change the class name from 'open' to 'active'.  (I used 'open' for demonstration purposes.)  If you want to post a quick demo on jsFiddle or enough of you're markup and css on here (as long as it's focused on this particular issue) it would help in debugging.

Comment: I also noticed  typo in my code snippet (it should have been 'hasClass' instead of 'hasclass').  That's what happens when I code without a debugger...

Comment: Thanks again Brian, i've put all the appropriate bits here...

Still not sliding down at all now :(

http://jsfiddle.net/mjVRj/1/

Comment: Sorry about that... my code was a bit off.  I forked your example here and got it to work... http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/U78Kh/  (I cleaned out a bit of the css while debugging, so it won't look exactly the same, but the logic should work.)  I had the slide events backwards.

Comment: Beautiful thats perfect, thank you so much :)

Tricky to add an active class to the a button you click to collapse the panel or not?

Comment: Not sure why the anchor would need a state class...  If I put it in, it was an error and you can probably safely remove it.  (Unless you need to track the anchor state for some other functionality.)

Comment: No i mean if i wanted an arrow for example to change when clicked or not clicked that would need to be on the a link not the panel, it looks like the active link is on the panel currently, unless i've read it wrong...

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Ah.  Yeah, go ahead and add/remove the class on the anchor tag when you open/close the panel.  It doesn't have to be the same class terms as the panel (because while it's a state indictor, it's for a different element) and make sure you're targeting your CSS so that whatever styling you want on the anchor won't also be applied to the panel and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at example 4a http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/